# Multiplication matrix on vector

Tags: c#, matrix, operator-overloading, matrix-multiplication

I need to multiply the matrix on the vector and print the result. There are classes of integer vector and integer matrix. When outputting, displays only the first element. Can you tell me what the error is? Below I show the overloading of the * operator that I made, the method for displaying the matrix and exactly how I display it. [Here is an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWyOY.png)

```
public class VectorInt//class VectorInt
        {
            protected int[] IntArray;
            protected uint size;
            protected int codeError;
            protected static uint num_vec;
            public VectorInt()
            {
                codeError = 1;
                size = 1;
                IntArray = new int[size];
                IntArray[0] = 0;
                num_vec++;
            }
            public VectorInt(uint n)//конструктор з одним параметром
            {
                codeError = 1;
                size = n;
                IntArray = new int[size];
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    IntArray[i] = 0;
                }
                num_vec++;
            }
            public VectorInt(uint n, int b)
            {
                codeError = 1;
                size = n;
                IntArray = new int[size];
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    IntArray[i] = b;
                }
                num_vec++;
            }

            ~VectorInt()
            {
                num_vec--;
                Console.WriteLine("Dipsosed");
            }

            public void Input()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nSize of vector: ");
                size = uint.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                IntArray = new int[size];

                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Element {0}: ", i);
                    Console.WriteLine(" v [ {0} ] = {1} ", i, IntArray[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
                }
            }

    public void Output()
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nMatrix");
                    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)//n-amount of rows
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)//m-amount of columns
                        {
                            Console.Write(" m [ {0}{1} ] = {2} ", i, j, IntArray[i, j]);
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine();
                    }
                }
public uint Size
            {
                get
                {
                    return (uint)IntArray.Length;
                }
            }
public int[] NewIntArray
            {
                get => IntArray;
            }
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
public class MatrixInt//class MatrixInt
        {
            protected int[,] IntArray;
            protected int n, m;
            protected int codeError;
            protected static int num_m;

            public MatrixInt()
            {
                n = 1; m = 1;
                IntArray = new int[n, m];
                IntArray[0, 0] = 0;
                num_m++;
            }
            public MatrixInt(int r, int c)
            {
                n = r; m = c;
                IntArray = new int[n, m];
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                        IntArray[i, j] = 0;
                }
                num_m++;
            }
            public MatrixInt(int r, int c, int b)
            {
                n = r; m = c;
                IntArray = new int[n, m];
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                        IntArray[i, j] = b;
                }
                num_m++;
            }
            ~MatrixInt()
            {
                num_m--;
                Console.WriteLine("Disposed");
            }

            public void Input()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Number of rows: ");
                n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Number of columns: ");
                m = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                IntArray = new int[n, m];

                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Element {0}{1}: ", i, j);
                        Console.WriteLine(" m [ {0}{1} ] = {2} ", i, j, IntArray[i, j] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
                    }
                }
            }

            public void Output()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nMatrix");
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                    {
                        Console.Write(" m [ {0}{1} ] = {2} ", i, j, IntArray[i, j]);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }
public int Rows
        {
            get
            {
                return n;
            }
        }
        public int Columns
        {
            get
            {
                return m;
            }
        }    

  
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public static MatrixInt operator *(MatrixInt obj, VectorInt obj1)
                    {
                        MatrixInt obj3 = new MatrixInt();
                         if (obj.Columns != obj1.NewIntArray.Length)
                        {
                                throw new Exception("Error!");
                        }
                        obj3.IntArray = new int[obj.Rows, 1];
                        for (int i = 0; i < obj.Rows; i++)
                        {
                            obj3.IntArray[i, 0] = 0;
                            for (int j = 0; j < obj.Columns; j++)
                            {
                                obj3.IntArray[i, 0] += obj.IntArray[i, j] * obj1.NewIntArray[j];
                                //Console.WriteLine(" m [ {0}{1} ] = {2} ", i, j, obj3.IntArray[i, 0]);
                            }
                        }
                        return obj3;
                    }
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                      MatrixInt obj = new MatrixInt();
                                    VectorInt obj1 = new VectorInt();
                                    obj.Input();
                                    obj.Output();
                                    obj1.Input();
                                    obj1.Output();
                                    obj *= obj1;
                                    obj.Output();
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell from the code you pasted in (for example, what are a `MatrixInt` and a `VectorInt` and what are the `IntArray` and `NewIntArray` properties?).  Your future self will appreciate it if you don't name your variables `obj` and `obj1`.  You may completely understand what they are today, but in a week or two you'll be wondering.  Name them `matrix` and `vector` or something like that.

Comment: @Flydog57, i will add some code for better understanding.

Comment: @Flydog57 I have added more useful information to my code

Comment: @Flydog57, do you have any suggestions?